# Allow user to clear date from DatePicker

Tags: wpf, datepicker, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have a DataGridTemplateColumn (created programatically) with a TextBlock for the CellTemplate, and a DatePicker for the CellEditingTemplate.

The DatePicker's value is bound to a DateTime?.

If the cell has a date when the grid is loaded, trying to clear the date results in validation problem -- the empty value is not sent to the bound property.
Is there a setting on the DatePicker to allow empty values (I couldn't find one)?
Is a converter needed to work with the nullable bound property?

Thanks for any insight --

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem but it was with a textbox for entering quantity of the product. It had an integer as binded property. It used to act correctly with some quanity entered. But when the textbox got empty after entering some value, then the property had the previous entered value as its current value.

I resolved this by putting a string type property as binded property.

You can do the same. Bind a string type Property with **DatePicker**. As the date is being picked with **DatePicker**, you are always sure of the date format. Also you can make **DatePickerTextBox** as readonly in app styles to not let user input any date by typing.

And in this way when you clear the **DatePicker**, The underlying binded property will contain null or empty string and I think that is what you are wanting.

You can use that string property in

`DateTime.Parse` Method to get an equivalent **DateTime** Object. Try parsing the date in try catch block to handle empty/null string case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Digging deeper in to the code, I found there is a converter involved.  I fixed the issue in ConvertBack() :  return `null` instead of `string.Empty`.

Comment: Great. Good to know you were able to solve it yourself. You didn't mention that you had a converter setup already in your code.